# Intent loaded URL not responding Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am still new to android studio and am trying to load a url when i click a button. However, in the url when I type my username and password, it doesnt go to next page, it just refreshes into the same page.

the codes i used are:

```
      bookingBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          Intent goToWebView = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
            goToWebView.putExtra("url", "https://www.airbnb.com/");
            goToWebView.putExtra("activityTitle", getString(R.string.home_booking_services));

            startActivity(goToWebView);
        }
    })
```

my WebViewActivity class file would be:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView myWebView;
private LinearLayout errorLayer;
private LinearLayout pBarLayer;
private ProgressBar pBar;

private String url = "";
private String activityTitle = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sofia_web_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);                                      // Web view in app
    pBarLayer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressBarLayer);                        // Progress bar layer
    pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    errorLayer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.errorLayer);

    pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    pBarLayer.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                                         // Enable Javascript
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());                                            // Open web link inside app
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress < 100 && pBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                pBarLayer.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }

            pBar.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                pBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                pBarLayer.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    SSLPinningWebViewClient webViewClient = new SSLPinningWebViewClient(new SSLPinningWebViewClient.LoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void Loaded(final String url) {


        }

        @Override
        public void PinningPreventedLoading(String host) {

            Log.e(host, host);
        }


    }, WebViewActivity.this);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("url")) {
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("activityTitle"))
            activityTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("activityTitle");

    }
    setTitle(activityTitle);

    myWebView.loadUrl(url);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                finish();

            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```

}

Anyone knows why the loaded page arent responding?
If there is any additional information needed, do let me know.TQ

Comment: Show us your `WebViewActivity` class file, also have you already register that activity in manifest?

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil have updated the WebViewActivity class file, sorry it may be a bit long, I didnt want to miss out any details, so show the whole file